# awk: sort file based on user input

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I have this simple `awk` code:

`awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $2,$1,$3}' $1`

Works great, except I've hardcoded how I want to sort the comma-delimited fields of my plaintext file. I want to be able to specify at run time in which order I'd like to sort my fields.

One hacky way I thought about doing this was this:

```
read first
read second
read third

TOTAL=$first","$second","$third

awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $TOTAL}' $1
```

But this doesn't actually work:

`awk: illegal field $(), name "TOTAL"`

Also, I know a bit about `awk`'s ability to accept user input:

```
BEGIN {
    getline first < "-"
}

$1 == first {
}
```

But I wonder whether the variables created can in turn be used as variables in the original print command? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to let `bash` expand `$TOTAL` before `awk` is called, so that `awk` sees the value of `$TOTAL`, not the literal string `$TOTAL`. This means using double, not single, quotes.

```
read first
read second
read third

# Dynamically construct the awk script to run
TOTAL="\$$first,\$$second,\$$third"
SCRIPT="BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $TOTAL}"

awk -F, "$SCRIPT" "$1"
```

A safer method is to pass the field numbers as awk variables.

```
awk -F, -v c1="$first" -v c2="$second" -v c3="$third" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {print $c1, $c2, $c3}' "$1"
```

Comment: I forgot to use `-v` for the other two variables.

Comment: Thanks, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
awk -v order='3 1 2' 'BEGIN{split(order,o)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $(o[i]), (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}'
```

e.g.:

```
$ echo 'a b c' | awk -v order='3 1 2' 'BEGIN{split(order,o)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $(o[i]), (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}'
c a b

$ echo 'a b c' | awk -v order='2 3 1' 'BEGIN{split(order,o)} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s", $(o[i]), (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}'
b c a
```